# Dynamically, add overlaping divs over each element (div, image, span,...) with specified class name (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to write a jQuery plugin with some visual effect for selected divs.
Integrating a plugin would look like so:

```js
$('.myclass').mypluginfunction();
```

Visually it would be a transparent div over the whole element, with moving background.

Is it possible to dynamically add divs without destroying e.g floated divs?

I know that the solution would be adding an absolute position to div with bigger `z-index.`

Comment: Yes it is! use z-index. Before you start writing jQuery plugins... take a look on HTML/CSS first

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to tinker with the z-index. An element lower in the source will overlay content before it. Set your elements to `position: relative` and append an absolutely positioned div with width and height set to 100% - this will effectively overlay it.

Get yourself Chrome (or Firebug) and play with [`$.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) in the console:

```
$('*').css('position', 'relative').append('<div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background: #F00; opacity:0.5;"></div>');
```

This will position every element on your site relatively, then append an absolutely positioned div with a red background. You should see every single element on your site being overlayed by it.

Of course this is going to explode, a little, but it gives you an idea of how easy to use this technique is.